# Non linked cell doesn't move with linked cell's row

Tags: excel, hyperlink, vba

I don't think my title will give you some idea on issue so, let me explain here.

I have excel worksheet which is an linked sheet. each rows are getting updated by another excel sheet. It's worked really fine. but since, last week I got an issue.

In my sheet, I have one column which is not linked. That column is left for other to update their comment. So, what happened is, once my sheet is updated, every rows gets moved up or down but those comments (adjacent cell to each linked cell) doesn't get moved.

Is there any idea to solve this issue? I don't really see solution here. But, it will be grateful if anyone could give solution on this.

Comment: @If you have control other the source worksheet (the one that is linked), add an `ID` column. Then add a hidden column next to the comment column called `ForRowId`. In this, store the ID of the row. When the workbook is opened, if the values and the `ID` and `ForRowId` Column are different then use VBA to move them around.

Comment: Hi Brownish,

It seems to be a nice idea. Yes. I have already a column called "Base no" Which is source sheet and same used in main sheet. Both should work together.

Unfortunately, no idea on VBA to proceed further. COuld you provide some hint on VBA coding?